# How to implement a default condition in all SQLAlchemy's queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `is_deleted` field in all tables which shows that this record has been removed (but it exists in tables).

So how to ignore (never consider) `is_deleted=True` records in all queries in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the sqlalchemy [event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#query-events) is the solution!

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Query, "before_compile", retval=True)
def no_deleted(query):
    for desc in query.column_descriptions:
        entity = desc['entity']
        if entity:
            query = query.filter(entity.is_deleted == False)

    return query
```

if you want specify model name(sqlalchemy model class name) such as 'User' in my case use this:

```
if entity == 'User':
    query = query.filter(entity.is_verified == True)
```

Comment: Can such filtering be done in the raw-sql / core level? say in a dialect where I want to filter and replace specific query types? My specific issue is with datetimes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027152/which-part-of-sqlalchemys-dialect-is-responsible-for-pre-processing-queries